# Elasticsearch reindex does the old data stay in destination

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question about the Elasticsearch reindex API. After I initiate a reindex, do the existing documents in the destination index get deleted or do they stay and only the new ones get added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reindex operation will by default override all documents in the destination index that already exist and have the same id.

If you want to prevent that you can use the `op_type: create` setting in order to only add missing documents in the destination index.

```
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "my_old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my_new_index",
    "op_type": "create"            <--- add this
  }
}
```

Comment: 1 will stay, 2 will be overridden with whatever version of that document is in the source index (unless `op_type: create` is specified) and 3 will be created

Comment: If I have document with id 1 and 2 in the destination index and then I reindex documents with ids 2 and 3. Then the document with id 1 will stay right? It won't be deleted? <-- edited. I wrote it wrong. Thanks! That's all i needed to know. :)